# Inserting space/gap between two main menu links

Tags: routes

In my main menu, I have the following links: Home, About Us, Blog, Log In and Sign Up.
I want the Log In and Sign Up links to float to the right such that there will be space/gap between the 'Blog' and 'Log In' links.

Please how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module to specify ids for those both menu then you try

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with wading into code, you can use _menu_item_alter() in your template.php to add CSS classes to just the menu items you want.